# Looking to stop ANY action on lid close on a Toshiba Tecra W50XUS2

Tags: windows-7, laptop, toshiba-laptop, laptop-display

My work laptop is a Toshiba Tecra W50XUS2 running Windows 7 and lots of IT-imposed software.

I have the lid close actions all set to "do nothing". But it must being doing SOMETHING because about 50% of the time when I open the lid, the screen is just black and the computer appears frozen. Reclosing/reopening the lid does not help. Plugging in an external monitor does not help. Ctrl Alt Del does not help. Mouse clicking does not help. At this point I'd rather have it not freeze than save the battery keeping the monitor lit.

I've tried to search for my problem but am not finding anything on the web that sounds similar. I fear it is related to all the corporate junkware I am forced to run. Is there a way I can stop closing the lid from taking ANY action?

Comment: Are your power options set to go into standby after a certain amount of time?

Comment: Nope actually all power options are off, "do nothing" type behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Device manager > system device > ACPI lid > disable

If that doesn't work it'll probably be a plug and play feature of the bios.

Comment: I hope it isn't premature but I think this has actually fixed my problem. A little more time will tell for sure. I actually instead set the ACPI lid to be a "Volume Manager" as suggested by a different SU question I found. I guess that has the same effect.